How do I get subsets from a list of tuples based on values within these tuples?
I have this list of tuples of which each contain a category, the count of this category and the data group it belogs to:
my_list = [ (category_1, 10, data_group_1), (category_2, 20, data_group_1), (category_2, 30, data_group_1),
(category_1, 5, data_group_2), (category_3, 20, data_group_2), (category_2, 10, data_group_3),
(category_3, 10, data_group_3) ]

The goal is to get a list in the form of:
my_list = [ data: [ (category_1, 10), (category_2, 20), (category_2, 30) ], group: 'data_group_1, 
data: [ ((category_1, 5), (category_3, 20) ], group: 'data_group_2, 
data: [ (category_2, 10), (category_3, 10) ], group: 'data_group_3 ]

I thought about sorting the list by the data group like this:
my_list.sort(key=lambda my_list: my_list[:][2])
then getting a set of the data group values:
for item in my_list: myset.add(row[2])
Ater these two steps I have no idea how to count he occurences of the tuples of data group x let alone getting the desired list.
I'm greatful for any ideas!
